# Copy and Paste from Tables with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

MS Excel 2016 VBA:

The following code works well except if the table is filtered. Any ideas on how to get around that without undoing the filtering?

Every day I need to copy the new column and paste it to the old column so we can track our daily progress.

I have additional code to unfilter, but I don't like the idea.

Suggestions?

```
Sub Table_Move()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim N As String
    Dim O As String

    Call Clear

    N = "New"
    O = "Old"

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    tbl.ListColumns(N).DataBodyRange.Copy
    tbl.ListColumns(O).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Table_Move()

    Dim N As String
    Dim O As String

    Call Clear

    N = "New"
    O = "Old"

    Range("Table1[" & N & "]").Copy
    Range("Table1[" & O & "]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

### Update

**Handle visible cells only**

```
Sub Table_Move()

    Dim N As String
    Dim O As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Call Clear

    N = "New"
    O = "Old"

    For Each rw In Range("Table1[" & N & "]").Cells

        If rw.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = rw
            Set Rng = Union(rw, Rng)
        End If

    Next rw

    Rng.Copy

    Range("Table1[" & O & "]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    

End Sub
```

### Also

```
Sub Table_Move()

    Dim N As String
    Dim O As String

    Call Clear

    N = "New"
    O = "Old"

    Range("Table1[" & N & "]").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Range("Table1[" & O & "]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work with the filtered rows

Comment: It copies range entirely contain filtered rows. If you need to copy only visible rows, now I have update above answer for this, else please say about your problem in working with filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will copy and paste each and every row from a data range, even if filter is on

```
Sub Move()
Dim rowcount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim sourceCol  As Integer, TargetCol As Integer

sourceCol = 14 ' Its N Column
TargetCol = 15 ' Its O Column
rowcount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row 'counts the rows with data
For currentRow = 1 To rowcount
    Range("O" & currentRow).Value = Range("N" & currentRow).Value 'Copy from N to O
Next

End Sub
```